# dropdown on change submit not executing php code

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

the form has multipe input type text and 1 dropdown menu.

I also have a submit button called (submit1)

```
<input class="submit-button" type="submit" name="submit1" value="UPDATE MY INFORMATION" />
```

My PHP read like this :

```
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) 
{ .... }
```

If I press the button, it works, no problem.

BUT I also want to submit the form from the dropdown menu change... so it can be executed by both the press of the button OR the change in dropdown... so I have the following for my dropdown

```
<select name="country"  onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

when I select my dropdown, the page refreshed, but the code in my PHP is not executed... I figured it has to do with the name of $_POST['submit1']...

How can I change onchange="this.form.submit()  for it to execute the code in if(isset($_POST['submit1']))...

Thank you

Comment: The submit button name-value-pair is not send when you submit the form via JavaScript – so don’t check for that, check for something else that your form sends in _any_ case.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid inline javascript like that. It's ugly, and reduces readability. The easier way would be to give your elements IDs, like so:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
```

But if you don't want to, you can use `QuerySelector` and grab the name attribute of your input.

```
var x = document.querySelector("[name='country']");
x.addEventListener("change",function() {
    this.parentNode.submit(); //get form parent and submit
});
```

I'm a bit confused why you're checking the submit button for a value as well, wouldn't you want:

```
if (isset($_POST['country'])) { ... }
```

Instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could just `document.getElementById('submit1').click()` after setting the `id` on your submit button the same as its name. Of course, you would also do this `onchange`. I would separate my JavaScript from HTML, so it's cached into your Browser memory. Give your inputs, selects and the like the same `id` as their name, with the exception of radio buttons, and possibly checkboxes.

Let's start with some `common.js`:

```
//<![CDATA[
var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
var IE = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split('MSIE')[1]);
bod.className = 'js';
function gteIE(version, className){
  if(IE >= version)bod.className = className;
}
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
//]]>
```

Now for your `otherpage.php`:

```
//<![CDATA[
var cntry = E('country'), sub1 = E('submit1');
cntry.onchange = function(){
  sub1.click();
}
// note that the format E('submit1').click(); would also work
//]]>
```

Of course, you should have:

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='common.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='otherpage.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for `isset($_POST['country'])`
And onchange add this to the drop-down,

```
onchange= 'document.getElementsByName("submit1")[0].click();'
```